# Is this valid C++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, language-lawyer

I have the following code that compiles under g++, but not with clang.

Clang will compile the code if changed in various minor ways, such as merging the 2 namespace declarations.

```
// The problem disappears without namespaces.
namespace Root {
    // The problem disappears if 'g' is in the global namespace, and we change
    // the friend declaration to '::g'

    // The problem disappears if 'g' has void return type.

    // The problem disappears if we get rid of the 'Value' template argument
    // and the 'value' parameter.
    template<typename Value, typename Defaulted = void>
    bool g(Value value);

    // The problem disappears if MyClass is not a template.
    template<typename ClassValue>
    class MyClass {
    private:
        template<typename Value, typename Defaulted>
        friend bool g(Value value);
    };
}

// The problem disappears if we declare the Root namespace in a single block
// containing 'g', 'MyClass' and 'f'.

// The problem remains if we declare f in the global namespace and reference
// Root::g.
namespace Root {
    void f() {
        MyClass<int> value;

        g(value);
    }
}
```

To compile with clang:

```
clang -fsyntax-only -std=c++11 testcase.cpp
```

To compile with g++:

```
g++ -fsyntax-only -std=c++11 testcase.cpp
```

Versions are g++ 4.9.2, clang 3.6.0, both on Ubuntu core 15.04.

Clang gives the error message:

```
testcase.cpp:24:9: error: no matching function for call to 'g'
        g(value);
        ^
testcase.cpp:14:21: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'Defaulted'
        friend bool g(Value value);
                ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: The friend function (even if declared in a class) has namespace scope. So in this case you have 2 function declarations for `bool Root::g()`. The template parameters don't change the declaration. That's why your minor changes make this code work. I am actually more surprised that this compiles with g++.

Comment: @SimonKraemer You're allowed to declare functions multiple times. And the `friend` declaration wouldn't redeclare the function anyway.

Comment: Is this your complete code or just the relevant part?

Comment: @Barry You're right. My fault. I tried to compile it with MSVC and went into linker errors. So I defined both g() functions..... -.-

Comment: @SimonKraemer, it's a greatly cut down version of the original problem. It was originally a problem with an assertion library interacting with an int library (to stop unsafe conversions - I was doing lots of bit twiddling).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is a clang bug. From [temp.param], we have:

> If a friend function template declaration specifies
>   a default *template-argument*, that declaration shall be a definition and shall be the only declaration of the
>   function template in the translation unit.
>
> The set of default *template-arguments* available for use is obtained by merging the default arguments from
>   all prior declarations of the template in the same way default function arguments are (8.3.6).

The latter point means that we can write:

```
template <typename T, typename U=int>
void h();

template <typename T, typename U>
void h() { }

h<int>();
```

And this is perfectly well formed code that clang compiles. We *cannot* specify the default template-argument to `g` based on the rule quoted, as `g` is previously declared, but *not* specifying it should still keep `Defaulted` available for use as `void` via the merge step. If the default-argument is available, then lookup should be able to find the `g` we want.

A workaround would be to simply friend the specialization we care about:

```
friend bool g<>(MyClass value);
```

Comment: Thanks - I agree with what you're saying about the merging, and that makes sense to me. But I thought you're not allowed to specify what a template param defaults to in a friend decl at all. Given that, my (mis)interpretation of the first paragraph would therefore be: By declaring a friend with a template param that already has a default (declared elsewhere), I have to provide the function body alongside the friend declaration?

Comment: After more thought, I understand now. You can specify defaults on a friend template, which I didn't realise, and that confused me. So this does look very much like a clang bug.